# Infinite Hamel basis for Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

What are some standard examples of Hamel basis for Banach spaces with cardinality >= $\aleph_0$? I tried searching, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://planetmath.org/banachspacesofinfinitedimensiondonothaveacountablehamelbasis
there is refference also.
Example is any Banach space of infinite dimension .

Comment: It says that the cardinality of Hamel basis for a banach space is uncountable(if not finite). I needed an example of uncountable basis.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wanted an example of Hamel basis with cardinality >=$\aleph_0$ for a Banach space.